# How can I sync Outlook to Google calendar in 2021?

Tags: calendar, outlook, google-calendar

What's the best (ideally free) updated way to sync Microsoft Outlook to Google Calendar in 2021?

I've exported my Outlook Calendar and imported into Google Calendar (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-an-outlook-calendar-to-google-calendar-662fa3bb-0794-4b18-add8-9968b665f4e6) multiple times, but it recently (~last 6 months) keeps breaking.

Tried Microsoft Flow (https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/f33ecb04e20f468ba284e6b413f6e4c2/outlookcom-calendar-to-google-calendar/) in the past but it broke too.

Tried IFTT (https://ifttt.com/applets/sAxNKLVc-outlook-calendar-to-google-calendar) but it broke too.

Thanks in advance!

Neil